# Would accepting a Christmas bonus make me hypocritical?

Tags: money, christianity, work, munafiq

I am someone who only celebrates 2 eids (celebrations), and don't recognize Xmas or even say happy holidays etc.

Now, would it be hypocritical of me to accept Xmas bonus? Also, if it is, could I accept it, and donate it, or would accepting it at all be a bad idea?

Comment: What sort of bonus is it?

Comment: @TamerShlash currency

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also get a Christmas bonus even though I don't personally celebrate the holiday. In general I think the time of year is just a convenient time to give out bonuses- you could just consider it to be a yearly bonus. It's not given out on the condition that you be an observing Christian- it's given out on the condition that you're a good worker and a loyal employee. I would advise that you accept it as such. I don't think it makes you indebted to them at all- employers don't give out bonuses as a favour unless you've explicitly asked for it. They're just, in a sense, paying you back for your hard work.

So in my opinion, go for it and think of it as a pat on the back rather than a celebration of a Christian holiday.

Comment: In India they give bonus around Diwali, a hindu festival.

Comment: @AbuAbdulQayyum- Again, I'm not a Hindu, but I'd still accept that bonus with thanks. If they implied that they thought I was a Hindu I'd correct them, regardless of the consequences, but I would assume my religion wouldn't matter unless otherwise indicated. And I'll always err on the side of honesty.

Answer (score 2):

```
           In the name of Allah, the Entirely Merciful, the Especially Merciful
```

According to my researches, seemingly, it is better not to accept the gift of non-Muslims. Since accordance to a general rule, the gift could make you indebted to them more than it indebted them to you (as an unwritten law), then that’s why if it is said attempt not to get …

Of course it could be considered from another aspect. In truth, in case that getting the gift (bonus which is counted as a gift) could make him/her Muslim (or to provide the fields of eagerness to Islam…) or even it would prevent you (as a Muslim) from annoying, then it could be permissible and rational to accept it.

As another point you'd better to notice that accepting the bonus doesn’t show them that you agree their celebration indirectly! Anyhow, survey the points, then make an appropriate decision according to the above-mentioned points

---

**Reference:** www.wikifeqh.ir